# How to create recurrence trees with level labels and work labels?

Tags: forest

I am trying to create recurrence trees to solve for time complexity of recurrences. This is my attempt so far, but the labels are all messed up and I can't seem to get the work labels working.

```
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw,
    minimum size=0.5cm,
    s sep=1cm,
    fit=band,
},
[{$n^2$}, name=level0
    [{$\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2$}, name=level1
        [{$\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2$}, name=level2
            [{$\vdots$}, name=vdots1
                [{$\left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)^2$}, name=leveli
                    [{$\vdots$}, name=vdots2
                        [{1}, name=base]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        [{$\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2$}]
        [{$\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2$}]
    ]
    [{$\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2$}]
    [{$\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2$}]
]
\node [anchor=west] at ([xshift=2cm]level0.east) {Level 0: $n^2$};
\node [anchor=west] at ([xshift=2cm]level1.east) {Level 1: $\frac{3n^2}{4}$};
\node [anchor=west] at ([xshift=2cm]level2.east) {Level 2: $\frac{9n^2}{16}$};
\node [anchor=west] at ([xshift=2cm]leveli.east) {Level i: $\frac{3^i n^2}{4^i}$};
\node [anchor=west] at ([xshift=2cm]base.east) {Base: $1$};
\end{forest}
```

This is how I want it to look: [image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please extend your code to a full ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. That way other users can just copy and paste your code. More users will be willing to help when there is a MWE.

Answer (score 4):

Use relative positions tanks to `-|`. The snippet below requires knowing which are the leftmost and rightmost nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      draw,
      minimum size=0.5cm,
      s sep=1cm,
      fit=band,
    },
    [{$n^2$}, name=level0
    [{$\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2$}, name=level1
    [{$\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2$}, name=level2
    [{$\vdots$}, name=vdots1
    [{$\left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)^2$}, name=leveli
    [{$\vdots$}, name=vdots2
    [{1}, name=base]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    [{$\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2$}]
    [{$\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2$}]
    ]
    [{$\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2$}]
    [{$\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2$},name=level1_3]
    ]
    \node (label0) [anchor=east, xshift=-1cm] at (level0-|leveli) {$0$};
    \node (wd0) [anchor=west, xshift=1cm] at (level0-|level1_3) {$n^2$};
    \node [above=2em of label0, font=\bfseries] {Level};
    \node [above=2em of wd0, font=\bfseries] {Work done};
    \node at (level1-|label0) {$1$};
    \node at (level1-|wd0) {$\frac{3n^2}{4}$};
    \node at (level2-|label0) {$2$};
    \node at (level2-|wd0) {$\frac{9n^2}{16}$};
    \node at (leveli-|label0) {$i$};
    \node at (leveli-|wd0) {$\frac{3^in^2}{4^i}$};
    \node at (base-|label0) {$\log_2n$};
    \node at (base-|wd0) {$3^{\log_2n}$};
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but maybe add `draw=none` to the nodes containing `\vdots`.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are the light of my life!

Answer (score 3):

You could make this as a single `forest` with a `phantom` root node.

Notes:

- `tier/.pgfmath=level()` aligns all levels
- `math content` is useful when your nodes are (mostly) typeset in math mode

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{mydots/.style={thick, dotted}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={if level=1{font=\bfseries}{math content}, tier/.pgfmath=level(), fit=band, s sep=1cm}
        [, phantom
            [Level[0, for tree={no edge}[1[2[\vdots[i[\vdots[\log_2n]]]]]]]]
            [[n^2, no edge, draw
                [\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2, draw
                    [\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2, draw
                        [, coordinate, for tree={edge=mydots}[\left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)^2, draw[, coordinate[1, draw]]]]
                    ]
                    [\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2, draw]
                    [\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2, draw]
                ]
                [\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2, draw[, edge=mydots]]
                [\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2, draw[, edge=mydots]]]]
            [Work done[0, for tree={no edge}[n^2, for tree={no edge}[\frac{3n^2}{4}[\vdots[\frac{3^i n^2}{4^i}[\vdots[1]]]]]]]
        ]]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tier/.option=level` would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

A semi-automatised version of Sandy G's great answer. It is still necessary to add `[]` around the contentful nodes for the phantom root, but the `Level` and `Work Done` labels are added automatically and much of the formatting is handled by the style `recurrence tree`. It would be relatively straightforward to have `forest` create the nodes' content, too, but I assume that's less likely to be useful since there's no need to construct identical trees. The overall style, `recurrence tree`, can instead be used to format trees with different content but the same general structure. (But there are a number of answers showing how to automatically generate trees like this, if you do want that.)

Note that `tier/.option=level` is a little quicker than the `.pgfmath` version and `s sep'=1cm` is faster than `s sep=1cm`. `pgfmath` is great, but rather slow. Since automation increases compilation time anyway, this code will still take longer to compile than Sandy G's.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709595/ addaswyd o ateb Sandy G: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709482/
\tikzset{mydots/.style={thick, dotted}}
\forestset{%
  recurrence tree/.style={%
    for root={phantom},
    for tree={%
      math content,
      tier/.option=level, 
      fit=band, 
      s sep'=1cm,
    },
    delay={%
      for nodewalk={fake=r,1}{replace by={[Level,font=\bfseries,delay=append]}},
      delay n=1{% delay={} doesn't work here but delay n=1{} does?
        for nodewalk={fake=r,3}{replace by={[Work Done,font=\bfseries,delay=append]}},
      },
      delay n=3{do dynamics},
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for nodewalk={r,1,tree,fake=r,3,tree}{%
        no edge,
        if content={}{coordinate}{},
      },
      for nodewalk={fake=r,2,tree}{%
        if content={}{coordinate}{draw},
        if={%
          > Ow+P {n children}{isodd(#1)}
        }{%
          calign=child edge,
          calign primary child/.process={Ow+n{n children}{(#1+1)/2}},
        }{},
      },
    },    
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  recurrence tree,
  [
    [0
        [1
          [2 [\vdots [i [\vdots[\log_2n] ] ] ]
          ]
        ]
    ]
    [n^2, no edge
      [\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2
        [\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2
            [, 
              for tree={edge=mydots},
                [\left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)^2
                  [
                    [1]
                  ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        [\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2]
        [\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2]
      ]
      [\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2
        [, edge=mydots]
      ]
      [\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2
        [, edge=mydots]
      ]
    ]
    [0
      [n^2, 
        [\frac{3n^2}{4} [\vdots [\frac{3^i n^2}{4^i} [\vdots [1] ] ] ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The output should be identical to the result of the original code:

[image: result of automatising tree]